# Use Special Character In Xml Element Name

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying generate xml file from string. One element has special characters in name and output should look like this:

```
<Discount %>10</Discount %>
```

I know it's not allowed but does "not allowed" mean that it's completely impossible or is it just a bad practice?

If it's possible how can I achieve it?

Here's my code

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
{
    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Client");

    xmlWriter.WriteElementString("Discount %", client.DiscountPercent.ToString());

    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
    xmlWriter.Flush();

    XmlDocument outputXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    outputXmlDocument.LoadXml(stringBuilder.ToString()); // throws this: System.Xml.XmlException: expected '>' (3E) but found '%' (25)  Line 1, position 618.
    File.WriteAllText(path, outputXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("Tables").OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: It's not C# question. Just check http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar

Comment: If you're unsure your element name is valid, you can use [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to guarantee the name is well-formed.  [`XmlConvert.DecodeName(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename(v=vs.110).aspx) is the inverse.

Comment: Consider using attribute `<Discount value="%">10</Discount>`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov that's interesting, I'll check it thanks

Comment: @dbc I know that, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element name must be in a single word.

and % should be avoided

Consider :

```
<Discount>  
<DiscountPercent>  
<Discount_Percent>
```